# generating and filling new data frames in lapply-"do not know how to convert x to class POSIXlt"

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to generate a new data frame containing weekly encounter histories for an animal based on one row in a data frame that contains the animal ID (BandNo) first and last day we tracked it (FDay, Lday), and the fate of the animal when we stopped tracking it (fate) as well as other covariates.

here is an example data frame for one individual, object "a"

```
structure(list(BandNo = structure(1L, .Label = c("1234", "4201", 
"4203", "4205", "4207", "4208", "4209", "4213", "4214", "4215", 
"4216", "4217", "4219", "4221", "4223", "4224", "4226", "4227", 
"4228", "4229", "4230", "4231", "4232", "4233", "4234", "4236", 
"4237", "4238", "4239", "4241", "4242", "4245", "4247", "4248", 
"4249", "4253", "4254", "4256", "4257", "4258", "4259", "4261", 
"4262", "4263", "4264", "4271", "4272", "4273", "4276", "4277", 
"4280", "4282", "4284", "4288", "4289", "4292", "4293", "4296", 
"4298", "4299", "4501", "4502", "4503", "4504", "4505", "4507", 
"4508", "4509", "4510", "4511", "4512", "4513", "4514", "4515", 
"4516", "4517", "4518", "4519", "4520", "4521", "4525", "4526", 
"4527", "4529", "4530", "4532", "4535", "4539", "4596", "4598", 
"4599", "6101", "6102", "6104", "6105", "6106", "6107", "6108", 
"6109", "6111", "6112", "6113", "6114", "6115", "6116", "6118", 
"6119", "8002", "8003", "8004", "8005", "8006", "8007", "8008", 
"8009", "8010", "8011", "8012", "8013", "8014", "8015", "8017", 
"8018", "8019", "8020", "8021", "8097", "8098", "8099", "8402", 
"8403", "8404", "8405", "8406", "8408", "8409", "8410", "8411", 
"8412", "8413", "8414", "8416", "8417", "8418", "8419", "8422", 
"8423", "8426", "8427", "8429", "8430", "8431", "8432", "8433", 
"8458", "8497", "8498"), class = "factor"), FDay = structure(1380171600, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Bogota"), Lday = structure(1392094800, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Bogota"), ObsLength = 138, Fate = "Predation", 
    FieldName = structure(7L, .Label = c("Bryan", "Dassow", "H1", 
    "H2", "NARD", "SAY160", "SAY320", "SAY40A", "Schaeffer", 
    "SIB", "Wessels"), class = "factor"), Landscape = structure(2L, .Label = c("CHW", 
    "SAY", "SIB"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(1L, .Label = c("F", 
    "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BandNo", "FDay", "Lday", 
"ObsLength", "Fate", "FieldName", "Landscape", "Sex"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

I can successfully create the new data frame I want (y) using this code :

```
library(lubridate)
mydate<-seq(from=a$FDay,to=a$Lday,by='week')
newband<-rep(a$BandNo,length(mydate))
newfate<-rep("Survive",length(mydate))
newfate[length(mydate)]<-a$Fate
y<-data.frame(newband,mydate,newfate)
y$FieldName<-a$FieldName
y$Sex<-a$Sex
y$Landscape<-a$Landscape
y$WeekID<-week(a$mydate)
y$Year<-year(a$mydate))
```

but when I try to apply it over a list of one-row data frames using the following code, I get the error message "do not know how to convert x to class POSIXlt"

the previous steps, used in lapply now, giving the error

```
b<-list(a)
d<-lapply(b,function(x){
mydate<-seq(from=x$FDay,to=x$Lday,by='week')
newband<-rep(x$BandNo,length(mydate))
newfate<-rep("Survive",length(mydate))
newfate[length(mydate)]<-x$Fate
y<-data.frame(newband,mydate,newfate)
y$FieldName<-x$FieldName
y$Sex<-x$Sex
y$Landscape<-x$Landscape
y$WeekID<-week(x$mydate)
y$Year<-year(x$mydate)})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the code as listed. First, you need an open and close bracket for the lapply. If you execute the code as it stands now, it will be a syntax error, and then you are likely to see an "Error: object 'x' not found", because after the syntax error the interpreter tries to evaluate then next line, at which point x is not found. Can you fix the code so that it evaluates.

Comment: I made those changes, sorry. Now there is a different error

 "Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Is it something simple like defining an as.POSIXct somewhere?

Comment: `x$mydate` is `NULL` because there is no column `mydate` in `x` and `NULL` can't be converted to `POSIXct`. Maybe it should just be `mydate` instead of `x$mydate`

Comment: oh man I am a dummy, It should be y$my date....thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a real bonehead mistake...I should have been referencing y$ mydate at the end. here is what that lapply function should look like:

```
d<-lapply(adult2,function(x){
mydate<-seq(from=x$FDay,to=x$Lday,by='week')
newband<-rep(x$BandNo,length(mydate))
newfate<-rep("Survive",length(mydate))
newfate[length(mydate)]<-x$Fate
y<-data.frame(newband,mydate,newfate)
y$FieldName<-x$FieldName
y$Sex<-x$Sex
y$Landscape<-x$Landscape
y$WeekID<-week(y$mydate)
y$Year<-year(y$mydate)
return(y)}
)
```